# Multiple errors asking me to rename

Tags: android

MainActivity.java - file

There's an error at "`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` - asking me to rename `onCreate` method
error on the line below that - There are no suggestions available

Another error at

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewByID(R.ID.edit_message); - edit_message cannot be resolved
```

Again, an error here `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);` - asking me to rename "main"

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void sendMessage (View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);

}


}
```

My displayMessage - java file

error at `setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);` - `active_display_message` cannot be resolved.

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    setContentView(textView);
}

/**
 * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupActionBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



}
```

Comment: did you `import android.R;` ? Any errors in your resource files?

Comment: Only errors on my SRC files.

Comment: Check under your gen folder, can you see r.java. If not then goto Project --> Clean.

Comment: I currently do not see that.  I have gone to clean and that is not generated after.

Comment: Screen shot of it ![http://i43.tinypic.com/k5388i.jpg](http://i43.tinypic.com/k5388i.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to restore `R.java`.

Edit your manifest file and save it. (Just put a space somewhere and delete it, then save.)

If this doesn't work, then just do a search for the solution(s) that work for you.

Note that `R.java` is auto-generated so you just need to make the system regenerate it.